# Can multiplication be defined without addition?

Tags: arithmetic, definition, axioms

I'm struggling to understand how to define multiplication and addition, now that I've been told that multiplication is not just repeated addition.

It seems that the axioms for the two are identical, save that multiplication is said to not have an inverse for the additive identity.

Doesn't this imply that multiplication cannot be defined without an addition?

Comment: It would help if you say what are the elements for which you are defining addition and multiplication, and even better if you quote the definitions.

Comment: Do you have abstract definitions of addition and multiplication? As far as I know, no such definitions exist.

Comment: As far as operations on natural numbers go, you can make axioms for multiplication that don't depend on addition.  See Skolem arithmetic.

Comment: What do you mean by multiplication? Do you mean multiplication in a field?

Comment: Multiplication in a field is where my question originated, but the concept of addition seems to always necessarily be derived from addition, despite the fact that I've read many arguments that multiplication is unique from addition.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique from addition"? You already know what multiplication and addition are; you've seen their defining properties in the field axioms yourself. Any two binary operations on a set satisfying all those properties can be called addition and multiplication. So what is it you really want to know I wonder? Just because multiplication isn't always repeated addition doesn't mean an existential crisis is at hand.

Comment: The axioms are all the same, except that it says that multiplication cannot have an inverse for the additive identity. Is that the only difference between the two? If so, then multiplication necessarily requires addition.

Comment: Sure. Who told you otherwise? People have told you multiplication is not repeated addition, that's all. That doesn't mean the defining properties of multiplication don't reference the addition operation at all (distributivity). One could say the only difference between a zebra and a zebrafish is that the latter has four extra letters appended to it, but that's a rather unenlightening perspective in my opinion (responding to the phrase "only difference between the two").

Comment: No one told me differently, that was my question. I wasn't sure if multiplication was some unique entity. Multiplication necessarily requires some idea of addition then.

Comment: At least for fields, yes. The operation on a group can be called either addition or multiplication (the former only when the group is abelian), and in *that* context if we call the group operation multiplication then it is not defined in terms of anything called addition.

Comment: Isn't multiplication abelian?

Comment: @Tony: some operations called "multiplication" are not Abelian, e.g. matrix multiplication, quaternion multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

Can you define multiplication with out addition? For natural numbers (i.e. $0,1,2,\dots$), sure. I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but it could be done as follows:

Let $0=\phi=\{\}$ (the empty set), $1 = \{0\}$, $2 = 1 \cup \{1\} = \{0,1\}$, $3 = 2 \cup \{2\} = \{0,1,2\}$, $\dots$

Define $m \times n = \{ (i,j) \;|\; i \in m \mbox{ and } j \in n\}$ (the Cartesian product of $m$ and $n$ -- all ordered pairs).  Then set $m \times n$ can be put into 1-1 correspondence with some natural number (set). Call this number $m \cdot n$. Voila! Multiplication.

Ok. Now for a reality check. When defining the natural numbers themselves I've used succession (i.e. plus one): $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$ (so there's addition hiding in the very definition of a natural number).

Next, if I were to actually **prove** that $m \times n$ is in 1-1 correspondence with some natural number, I would almost certainly end up developing addition to do so.

So can you avoid addition? Yes and no. But necessarily in an unnatural way.

Exponentiation is repeated multiplication: $m^n = m^{n-1}m$. Multiplication is repeated addition: $mn = m(n-1)+m$. Addition is repeated succession:
$m+n = m+(n-1)+1$. It's just a natural hierarchy of operations.

All arithmetic for bigger number systems flows from this.

Comment: The question wasn't clear to me, not knowing the "previous question" , answer withdrawn

Comment: Who's to say that this multiplication isn't to be called addition though? What is the difference between multiplication and addition?

Comment: In [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/Q589mrWD) example, can you explain how the cartesian product $m\times n$ corresponds to the arithmetic product of the numbers that sets $m$ and $n$ represent? I.E. how do you show that the sets $Succ(1)\times Succ(2)$ and $Succ(5)$ contain one another, and are thus equal?

Comment: [I'll denote successor of n as n' here.] So 1' × 2' = 2 × 3 = 6 = 5'. And the Cartesian product of sets 1' × 2' has the same number of elements as 5'. But it is not true that the sets 1' × 2' and 5' are equal  (as sets). One can show there is an algorithm to turn such a Cartesian product into successors of 0. This amounts to some of peano's axioms: https://billcookmath.com/courses/math2510-spring2010/Proofs_in_PA.pdf

Comment: I worked out your request (more or less) as an example here: https://billcookmath.com/courses/math2110-fall2020/math2110-fall2020-homework5.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You can define multiplication
without using addition
by using similar triangles in
Euclidean geometry.

Once a unit length is specified,
you can get $a*b$
by solving
$\dfrac{a}{c}
=\dfrac{1}{b}$.
To do this,
have two lines from a point P.
The first has a point $A$ with
$|PA| = a$.
(Note: $|UV|$ is the distance between points
$U$ and $V$.)
The second line
has points $B$ and $C$
with
$|PB|=1$
and
$|PC| = b$.
Draw a line through $C$
parallel to $AB$.
This intersects the first line
at a point $D$
such $|PD| = c$.